# In db2 how to select a column in integer having aligned it to right with leading spaces?

Tags: sql, db2, cobol, mainframe

I need to extract a report from some tables using db2 having pgm(dnatiaul).
Using a query i want to get the below output with first char to be spaces.

ex: integer(16)

---

```
 54457750
 49457750
```

o/p: char(int(16))

---

```
       54457750
       49457750
```

As i am trying to convert it to char it is aligning to left.

I tried Lpad which gives me **extra length i.e (18) + '.' also 
Help me

Comment: Why the COBOL tag on your question?

Answer (score 2):

`LPAD` is the right choice, but you would need to specify how long the result string needs to be. This can be done using `CAST`. Here I cast the result to 10 characters.

```
db2 "select cast(lpad(123422,10,' ') as char(10)) as testme from sysibm.sysdummy1"

TESTME    
----------
    123422

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

`DIGITS(integer_column_name)` will give you a character string of `CHAR(10)` with the numeric value right-justified and left-filled with zeroes. Thus, an integer column containing `543210` will become a character string containing `0000543210`.

Likewise, `DIGITS(small_integer_column_name)` will give you a character string of `CHAR(5)`